# Protecting a wood bathroom floor

Tags: bathroom, wood, floor

We recently had our house renovated and two of the bathrooms now have bare wooden floors. At some point I'll get round to putting down tiles or vinyl but for the time being what should I do to protect the wood from water? One floor is ordinary floorboards and the other is plywood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get vinyl sheets really cheap especially if you don't care how they look.  I have picked up a decent sized sheet for $20 on craigslist.

Your other option is polyurethane.  2-3 coats will give you a decent barrier for the water.